# Determine $(\vec{u} ∧ \vec{v}) ·\vec{w}$ for vectors which do not make use of unit vectors.

Tags: vectors

The three vectors $vec{a}, vec{b} and vec{c}$ are mutually orthogonal vectors in $R^{3}$ such that the triad $(\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c})$ is a right–handed triad and $|\vec{a}| = 1, |\vec{b}| = 2$ and $|\vec{c}| = 3$.

The vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are given in terms of the basis vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ as follows:

$\vec{u} = 3\vec{a} + 3\vec{b} − \vec{c}$

$\vec{v} = \vec{a} + 2\vec{b} + 3\vec{c}$

$\vec{w} = \vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c}.$

Determine $(\vec{u} ∧ \vec{v}) · \vec{w}$.

How can I find the cross product of two vectors which do not make use of unit vectors?

Comment: Up to the sign, the triple product $(\vec{u}\wedge\vec{v})\cdot\vec{w}$ is the volume of the box generated by $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't compute the cross product and dot product separately, but make use of the scalar triple product immediately.

So
\begin{align*}
(u\times v)\cdot w&=[u,v,w]\\
&=[3a + 3b − c,a + 2b + 3c, a + b + c]\\
&=\det\begin{pmatrix}3&3&-1\\1&2&3\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}[a,b,c]\\
&=4[a,b,c]\\
&=4\lvert a\rvert\cdot\lvert b\rvert\cdot\lvert c\rvert\quad\text{since }(a,b,c)\text{ right-handed triad}\\
&=\dots
\end{align*}